# C# SqlException was unhandled error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified

Tags: c#, sql

He estado desarrollando desde principios de diciembre del 2016 un proyecto para registrar vales de préstamo de herramientas para mi escuela y he echo uso de una base de datos sql para llevar el registro. Agregué una base de datos local sql siguiendo el siguiente tutorial de youtube:

"Consultas de Insertar Modificar Borrar y Buscar en VB 2010 y 2008"
(el vídeo dura 17 minutos con 45 segundos no puedo agregar el link porque tengo bajo nivel en el foro, además que en el vídeo el autor programa en C++ y yo programe en C#)

Y después de haber manejado bastante las consultas (los Queries) de la base de datos (que funcionan correctamente) quise agregarle un form para respaldar la base de datos siguiendo el siguiente tutorial:

http://www.csharp-tutorials.info/2016/03/backup-and-restore-sql-server-database.html

cuando intenté realizar un respaldo no hacia nada y entonces puse como comentario las instrucciones try y catch para ver el error al intentar de nuevo me apareció el siguiente error:

> SqlException was unhandled
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

y les dejo la captura de pantalla del error:
[image: Captura de pantalla del error]
a continuación les pongo el código completo del form:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Base_de_datos_ITQ
{
    public partial class Respaldo_duv : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Base_de_datos_ITQ.Properties.Settings.Default.Base_de_datosConnectionString);
        public Respaldo_duv()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_duv_examinar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FolderBrowserDialog dialogo = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (dialogo.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox_duv_dirección_respaldo.Text = dialogo.SelectedPath;
            }
        }

        private void button_duv_respaldar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string database = con.Database.ToString();
            //try
            {
                if (textBox_duv_dirección_respaldo.Text == string.Empty)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("please enter backup file location");
                }
                else
                {
                    string cmd = "BACKUP DATABASE [" + database + "] TO DISK='" + textBox_duv_dirección_respaldo.Text + "\\" + "database" + "-" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss") + ".bak'";

                    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmd, con))
                    {
                        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                        {
                            con.Open();//aquí es donde se marca el error
                        }
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();
                        MessageBox.Show("database backup done successefully");
                    }
                }

            }
            //catch
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notese que esta escrito en lenguaje C#.

Debo agregar que estoy estudiando ingeniería electrónica y no sistemas o computación, por tanto no estoy en mi campo (normalmente lo que programo son microcontroladores con C++, es decir lenguajes de bajo nivel) y es la primera vez que utilizo bases de datos sql. doy gracias de antemano a todos los que respondan.

Comment: Puedes poner la cadena de conexión que estas utilizando para acceder a la base de datos?

Comment: ¿te refieres a esta?: Data Source=C:\Users\Manuel\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Base de datos ITQ\Base de datos ITQ\Base_de_datos.sdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo al comentario donde indicas la ruta de la base de datos a la cual te estas conectando, puedo deducir que estas trabajando con `SQL Compact Edition`, esto debido a la extensión del archivo `.sdf`. Esto significa que para crear la conexión no puedes utilizar `SqlConnection` lo correcto seria que usaras `SqlCeConnection` que es el controlador adecuado para este tipo de base de datos. Lo mismo pasa con la clase `SqlCommand` deberías utilizar `SqlCeCommand`.

**EJEMPLO:**

```
SqlCeConnection conn = null;

try
{
    conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source = MyDatabase.sdf; Password ='<pwd>'");
    conn.Open();

    SqlCeCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Customers ([Customer ID], [Company Name]) Values('NWIND', 'Northwind Traders')";

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
finally
{
    conn.Close();
}
```

Ahora bien, creo que la instrucción `BACKUP DATABASE....` que estas intentado usar para realizar el **Backup** tampoco te va a funcionar, por que esta es una instrucción para SQL Server o SQL LocalDB.

Para hacer **Backup** a un archivo .sdf basta solo con copiarlo, como se hace con cualquier otro archivo en el disco, lo único que tienes que asegurar antes de copiarlo es que no haya ningún usuario conectado a la base de datos en ese momento.

Al final de esta referencia https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172411(v=sql.110).aspx puedes encontrar  lo que te estoy diciendo.

Comment: Eres un bruja! muchas gracias. Pero con eso me surge una pregunta: ¿como puedo respaldar cuando el programa lo instalo en otra pc con un publish? es decir, ¿donde guarda la base de datos sql cuando genero el ejecutable del programa?

Answer (score 0):

El error que te muestra significa básicamente que no encuentra la base de datos por lo cual podemos asumir en principio que hay algo incorrecto en el connection string.
Por otra parte veo que utilizas una base de datos *.sdf* que corresponde a *SQL Server Compact Edition* por lo cual no es correcto utilizar

> System.Data.SqlCommand

Esto se utiliza cuando te conectas a una base de datos que esta corriendo en el motor de MSSQL instalado en el servidor.

Para utilizar *SQL Server Compact Edition* tendrías que utilizar

> System.Data.SqlServerCe

No entiendo como te han funcionado las otras consultas sobre una base .sdf utilizaste *System.Data.SqlCommand*.

De todos modos, como es un archivo de tipo *.sdf*, no se generan *.bak* para los respaldos como lo harías en un *MS SQL Server* tradicional es decir con una instancia de MSSQL corriendo en el servidor.

**Estas bases de datos más sencillas como se corresponden simplemente con un archivo, basta con hacer una copia de este y guardarla donde sea deseado.**